# Prove an inequality without using Jensen's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponentiation, jensen-inequality

I have created a new one this is the following :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a^a+b^b+c^c=3$ then we have :
>   $$a+b+c\leq 3$$

I have tried to use Jensen's inequality like this :

$$(a+b+c)\ln(\frac{a+b+c}{3})\leq a\ln(a)+b\ln(b)+c\ln(c)\leq 3\ln(\frac{a^a+b^b+c^c}{3})$$

My question is how to prove it without using Jensen's inequality ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why not use Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x \le x^x $ holds for all positive real numbers:
$$ 
x \le x^x \iff \log x \le x \log x  \iff 0 \le (x-1) \log x 
$$
which is certainly true. Therefore
$$
a + b + c \le a^a+b^b+c^c = 3
$$
with equality exactly for $a=b=c=1$.

---

Your proof does not work because
$$
(a+b+c)\ln(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c})\leq a\ln(a)+b\ln(b)+c\ln(c)
$$
does not hold in general, try e.g. $(a, b, c) = (1, 1, 0.5)$.

Comment: That's a slick one!